# COMAPIを使用して取得したオブジェクトをXMLに出力する

Tags: c#, xml, com

こんにちは。COMAPIを使用して取得したE-CADの作図データのオブジェクト情報をXMLに出力するようにしたいですができていません。VisualStudio2019のC#を使用して行っており、Windows画面のボタンを押下すれば、作図データのオブジェクトが
xmlファイルに出力されるようにしたいと考えています。現在は、ボタン押下後、xmlシリアライザーがCOMObjectにアクセスしようとして失敗します。何か他に考えることはあるでしょうか？そもそもXMLに出力不可の場合、出力するのに何か良い方法はあるでしょうか？出力方法はファイル等なんでもよいですが、、

```
        dynamic ecadAppObj = Interaction.GetObject(null, "EcadAuto.EcadApplication");
        dynamic ecadUIService = ecadAppObj.GetService("EcadAuto.EcadUIService");
        IEcadUISelection iEcadUiSelection = ecadUIService.Selection();

        var ecadCreateDbSearchCondition = ecadAppObj.CreateDbSearchCondition();
        var ecadSelectedObjects = iEcadUiSelection.SelectedObjects;
        //
        Type typeOfDataSet = ecadSelectedObjects.GetType();

        //
        var ecadDiagramInfo = ecadSelectedObjects.Document().DiagramInfo();
        //
        Type typeOfEcadDiagramInfo = ecadDiagramInfo.GetType();

        //XMLの作成
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeOfEcadDiagramInfo);
        var path = @"C:\Data\test.xml";
        System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(path);

        writer.Serialize(file, ecadDiagramInfo); //→ここでエラー
        file.Close();
```

エラーメッセージ
TypeAccessException: メソッド 'Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter__ComObject.Write4___ComObject(System.Object)' が型 'System.__ComObject' にアクセスしようとして失敗しました。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーが発生することは分かりますが、ではどのような結果を求めているのでしょうか？ つまり、XmlSerializerに対してこのCOMオブジェクトはどのようなXMLに変換されることを期待されているのでしょうか？ 具体的なXMLタグを示してください。

Comment: この辺の記事が何かヒントになるかもしれません。[3rd party COM object cannot be serialized. Even if wrapped as a DataMember](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10341286/9014308), [How Do I serialize a COM object in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085620/9014308), [WCF Serialization of DLR dynamic types](https://loosexaml.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/wcf-serialization-of-dlr-dynamic-types/), [Serialize a COM object to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52411499/9014308)

Comment: @sayuri XMLには、いくらか種類があるということでしょうか？COMオブジェクト内の中身を全てXMLで出力したいと思います。イメージは以下のような感じなるでしょうか。
`<ActiveDocument>
 <Appication>
  <XXXXXX>
  </XXXXXX>
     ・・・
 </Appication>
 <DiagramInfo>
  <YYYYYYY>
  </YYYYYY>
     ・・・
 </DiagramInfo>
        <Path>"C\\temp\</Path>
        <Name>"Test.ADD"</Name>
</ActiveDocument>`

Comment: `ActiveDocument Application DiagramInfo`でググってみましたが該当するXMLがヒットしませんでした。XML Schemaを提示してください。

Comment: @sayuri 連絡が遅くなり申し訳ありません。それらはECAD専用のオブジェクト名なので、ネット上でヒットできなさそうかと思います。その情報を伝えられず申し訳ないです。現状、オブジェクト丸ごとXMLに出力するようなことは厳しそうなので、仕様を見ながら丁寧に出力するようにしていきます、、

Comment: @kunif ありがとうございます。COMオブジェクトを取り出して、XMLに出力は厳しそうです。@sayuriさんの方でご連絡しましたが、そちらの方法で行っていきたいです。